# Scaleable backend - self hosted?

Tags: api, scalability, backend

I'm currently working on a project (basically an app for iOS and Android + Backend), which needs to be highly scaleable. As we'd like to host everything on our own servers, MBaaS are not an option.
The problem now is, that I'm not sure where to start with the backend. Are there any useful "tools"/"server"-software out there, which provide a good start?
Thank's for you're thoguhts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interessted.. You may want to start with the Play-Framework or Sails.js (based on node.js).